# Move express app from local to a server with a domain

Tags: node.js, express

The goal is, in apparence, simple. I've a backend run perfect in localhost in my computer make with express and node, all my endpoints is localhost:3000/login, localhost:3000/register, etc. All run and work perfect.

What I want?.

Well, i've a cloud server and i've a subdomain called api.mydomain.com. The objetive is upload the express project to my webserver and this serve the endpoints that api.mydomain.com/login, api.mydomain.com/register and works equals works in local (the connections to the database are remote, don't problem for this).

I'm affraid, read and read tutorials in internet and not found any easy way to implement this.

I'ts hosting problem?, i'ts ports problem?.

I've connected to the server via SSH and in the subdomain's folder can call "npm run start" and the console show "server listening from port 3000", but... api.mydomain.com/login thrown any plesk page error and api.mydomain.com:3000/login simply thrown timeout.

NOTE: The server runs version 18 of node and all dependencies have installed in the remote folder project, same as local!.

NOTE 2: The webserver is a Apache based webserver in ubuntu 20, with plesk as admin server panel and in this server are more webs. Maybe better mount a server only for this purpouses?

Thanks in advance.

I've tried in postman passed body JSON data to work (email and password for route login for example), but timeout or any unexpected response is obtained from server, and 500 status code.

Comment: Firewall(s). Where is your server hosted?

Comment: Hi @pierpy, is a cloud server in clouding.io. Server administration is complety mine. I've complete control of this. Server is Ubuntu 20.04 based SO and plesk to admin server services. I've total connection root from SSH.

Comment: Ok, are you sure that port 3000 can be reached from internet?  Are you logging reqs in server console?

Comment: Hi @pierpy, it's solved, and if you question me why.... I can't answer. Just wait... it is the secret, i'm waiting a few hours and the end points runs perfect!, and without specific por 3000. The web server catch the request and automatically filter to the localhost:3000 internal address that aims to express app in the given domain. Rare, but, works... Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
It's solved, and if you question me why.... I can't answer. Just wait... it is the secret, i'm waiting a few hours and the end points runs perfect!, and without specific por 3000. The web server catch the request and automatically filter to the localhost:3000 internal address that aims to express app in the given domain. Rare, but, works... Thanks for all.